# iPhone Authorize.Net SDK integration

Tags: iphone, sdk, authorize.net

I am trying to integrate iPhone SDK into my project. (AIM)
I have some dificulties and I can't make it work.

I have followed the guide https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios

```
AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];
[an setDelegate:self];
[an mobileDeviceLoginRequest: mobileDeviceLoginRequest];
```

In the code above, `an` remains null because the class AuthNet doesnt instantiate while calling `getInstance()`.

In the README file, it says that I have to call

```
[AuthNet authNetWithAPILoginID:@"YOUR_LOGIN_ID" andTransactionKey:@"YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY" forEnvironment:ENV_TEST];
```

in order to instantiate the singleton. BUT there is no such method inside "AuthNet" class.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

```
 -(void)registerDevice
    {
       MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest *registrationRequest=[MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest];

       registrationRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name=@"loginid";

       registrationRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.password = @"password";

       registrationRequest.mobileDevice.mobileDescription=@"asd";
       registrationRequest.mobileDevice.mobileDeviceId=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
                                                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];    
       [AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_TEST];
       AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];

       [an setDelegate:self];

       [an mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest:registrationRequest];

    }
```

Call this method 1st to register ur device.

Comment: i am doing same so i have tried your code , i am getting error while trying to registerDevice AS
namespace warning : xmlns: URI AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd is not absolute
ttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd".
Please Help me where i am wrong

Comment: which account ur using sandbox testing account or live account?

Comment: Interesting how your rather simple and short answers all get around 10 up votes.

Comment: this error occurs when ur device is not registered.So write above method to register your device and replace it with ur credentials

Comment: I have tried doing the same above but it seems that the uniqueIdentifier method is deprecated so i tried the identifierForVendor method instead and i am getting the error which says The value '<__NSConcreteUUID 0x1c5af630> xxxxxxx' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The actual length is greater than the MaxLength value Message.code = E00003 so what could be the mistake in this case.

Comment: @Radix just make sure you are getting a proper device id. Try with some constant and then try

Comment: @Dhara i am always getting transaction unsuccessful after successful register & log-in with sandbox account. 
Can you help me for make further code after log-in?.

Comment: @Dhara For Create Transaction Request?

Comment: when i tap swipe button on demo then i get error: "Error Code and Msg E00061 : Device information is not formatted correctly(1).". what this error say?  my card info not read using demo.pls help me.