# Authorize.net device is not registered with this merchant account?

Tags: iphone, ios, authorize.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Authorize.Net SDK integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104806/iphone-authorize-net-sdk-integration)
>   [Register device using test account on authorize.net iphone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326900/register-device-using-test-account-on-authorize-net-iphone-sdk)

I created a test account on authorize.net and used the basic code given on the website for the integration of the sdk. The request is sent successfully but every time i get response that "This device is not registered with this sdk. When i log in the sandbox account there are no devices to approve/enable. I am stuck in this for hours.. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use this method to register the device http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104806/iphone-authorize-net-sdk-integration/9411430#9411430%60 and then check by logging into ur sandbox and u will find a device request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the README in their SDK (emphasis mine):

> Run your sample app and when you click on the "Authorize and Capture"
>   button, you should be prompted with a dialog that asks you to enter in
>   your Login Id and Password. These are your Authorize.Net account login
>   credentials.  **If this is the first time you are  performing this
>   login from a new device (either real or virtual), the login will fail
>   and state that the device has been registered but is pending approval.
>   You will need to login to the  sandbox and enable the new device.  You
>   can find this by going to :**
>
> **Home > Account (Settings) > Security Settings (Mobile Device Management)**
>
> **Once there, you should see your new device in a 'Pending' state.  Click on it and enable  it.  Click on the Login button again, and the
>   transaction should succeed and you will be prompted with an authCode
>   and refTransId.**

Comment: when i first perform login, i go to my account on authorize.net and i don't see my device in Mobile Device Management. Thats the problem, i have the read the documentation already.

Comment: i figured it out, we need to register the device first by sending a separate device registration request.