# Register device using test account on authorize.net iphone SDK?

Tags: ios, authorize.net

Can someone provide me a code snippet to register my device using authorize.net test account. I am using aim sdk for iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From A[uthorize.Net support](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Registering-an-iPhone-as-a-device-for-testing/m-p/19480/message-uid/19480#U19480):

> If they are referring to the actual app please be advised that
>   currently the app will not work for test accounts but if they are
>   talking about the SDK, they will need to register the phone first by
>   using “MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest” the first time they use a new
>   phone. The phone will show up for approval in their Settings page when
>   they login to their Authorize.Net account. Once they approved it they
>   can login by using “MobileDeviceLoginRequest”.

Comment: were you able to get the transaction history? I have a settled transaction in my test account but when i sent the request from my app it returns that no record was found. Is it something related to settled/unsettled transactions?

Comment: Hello Saleh,JohnConde
i am doing same,i am  getting error while trying to registerDevice AS
namespace warning : xmlns: URI AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd is not absolute
ttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd".
Please Help me

Comment: Please this is urgent. Reply ASAP. To be able to interact with API, we need session token. Is AuthNet credentials the only way of getting session token? We don't want to give AuthNet credentials to our employees who will be making this transactions. Isn't there a way to use a permanent key (which is hardcoded into app) to authorise merchant account?

Answer (score 0):

Code For registration of device

```
MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest *registrationRequest=[MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest];
registrationRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name= @"Current API Login ID";
registrationRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.password = @"Current Transaction Key";

registrationRequest.mobileDevice.mobileDescription=@"Description";
registrationRequest.mobileDevice.phoneNumber = @"Mobile no.";
registrationRequest.mobileDevice.mobileDeviceId=   @"Device udid";

[AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_TEST];
AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];
[an setDelegate:self];
[an mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest:registrationRequest];
```

Remember that once device is register from site
  than  comment the below code

```
[an mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest:registrationRequest];
```

because once device is registered then no need to register again other wise give give error.

Comment: Can You Suggest in ENV_LIVE environment we have to enter API Login ID and Transaction ID as same code you given above?